# Anyone Know how to get product attributes from the scrapes plugin for Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I just Recently installed the octolooks scrapes plugin for wordpress. I am trying to scrape product attributes for a woocommerce site but I am unable to. I talked to support for the plugin but they said that scrape product attributes isn't fully supported, meaning it can get product attributes some how, but I dont know how. Does anyone out there know how?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: First I tried going through the interface and selecting the product attributes. After that I tried putting in the name of the product attributes I wanted scrapes to get and that also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "CUSTOM FIELDS" and add new custom filed, select the filds in dropdown form and select element on target page
[CUSTOM FIELDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj5ux.jpg)

Comment: Hi karakym, I'm trying to get product attributes as well, but I can't get it done with the information you give. I wonder if you could give more details on this.